# Why one of my ssh keys on github became grey(it was green) and doesn't work anymore?

Tags: git, github

I have two github accounts and i hadn't used one of them for a while.

Today i decided to add some refs to it, but in my github settings, ssh key became grey for some reason, so i couldn't push successfully.
I had to create new ssh key because of that.

How do i avoid this problem in the future?

```
ERROR was: Permission to one-of-my-acc denied to Name.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you described is the error you get when you try to `fetch/push/push` without the right keys.

In your case it looks like your key was `revoke` - become inactive.

I could not find any documentation about it in `github` and according to their docs there is no way to `revoke` the key manually.

The solution you followed is the right one.

Comment: This is likely due to DSA keys being disabled on pretty much all updated OS's, including GitHub, as pointed out in @chendianbuji's answer. Best switch to RSA keys if your old key is DSA.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem like yours.
I use a `ssh-dsa` key on github. One day it doesn't work any more.

[OpenSSH 7.0 has disabled ssh-dsa](https://www.gentoo.org/support/news-items/2015-08-13-openssh-weak-keys.html):

> Starting with the 7.0 release of OpenSSH, support for ssh-dss keys has
>   been disabled by default at runtime due to their inherit weakness

You can find how to config to restart using `ssh-dsa` on Internet. But I tried to edit my /etc/ssh/sshd-config and ~/.ssh/config, and find that ssh-dsa still don't work for github.

So I recommand you to use `ecdsa` or `rsa` instead of `dsa`, it is a good chance for you update your ssh key.

Comment: I believe dsa keys are being refused on the GitHub side (so there's nothing you can do locally), as is also the case with (all?) updated linux distro's (read any updated server you ssh to). Best to make an RSA key and replace the DSA public keys on all the systems you ssh to.